# Return result of postgresql query onto a html page

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask, cs50

I am creating a book review website for CS50. I am having an issue displaying a query.The problem lies in the /books directory. The books.html contains a form with 3 inputs: isbn,title,author, and a submit button. Once I click the submit button it redirects to the login page. My goal is to output it to the user. If anyone could help me out, it would be really helpful.I get the error:

TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable

```
 import os

from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

# Configure session to use filesystem

app.secret_key = 'key'
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"


# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

@app.route("/")
def index():

    return render_template('index.html', navbar=True)

@app.route("/register",methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        cpassword = request.form.get('cpassword')

        if not password == cpassword:
            return render_template('error.html', message='Passwords do not match')

        avail = db.execute('SELECT username FROM userdetails WHERE username=:username',
                                {'username': username}).fetchone()

        if avail:
            return render_template('error.html', message='Username Already Exists')

        db.execute('INSERT INTO userdetails(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)',
         {'username': username, 'password': password})
        db.commit()

        session["username"] = username

        return redirect('/')

    else:
        return render_template('register.html')

@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        user = db.execute('SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE (username=:username AND password=:password)',
                             {'username': username, 'password': password}).fetchone()

        if user is None:
            return render_template('error.html', message='Entered credentials not valid!')

        session["username"] = username

        return redirect('books')

    else:
        return render_template('login.html', navbar=False)



   @app.route("/books", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def books():

    isbn = request.form.get('isbn')
    title = request.form.get('title')
    author = request.form.get('author')

    result = db.execute('SELECT * FROM books WHERE (isbn=:isbn AND title=:title AND author=:author)',
                             {'isbn': isbn, 'title': title, 'author': author}).fetchall()


    return render_template('books.html')

@app.route("/result", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
    if request.method == 'POST':
      result = request.form()
      return render_template("result.html",result = result)
```

Books.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Books</title>
</head>
<form method="POST" action="/result">
  <input type="number" name="isbn" placeholder="isbn">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title">
  <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="author">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Result.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  {{result}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure how would you consume the data but from the api end you need to make it serializable in the form of json object or json list which can be read by your view.Create a mapper utility function to map the object to a dict which can be converted to a json. and please change the title you do not want to *" print the postgres query"* you want to return the results of the query

Comment: Woah, bro can you explain that in simpler terms? I changed tne title as per your request.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is this `<form method="POST" action="/login">` in book.html. It is sending user back to the login page. [From the spec](https://docs.cs50.net/web/2018/x/projects/1/project1.html), it seems the `books` route is from the `search` page (with "reviews" not yet implemented). The "book" page should allow user to enter a rating and review, and on submit presumably update the "reviews" table in the database (as suggested by the first Hint). It looks like the book page is not complete.

This line `result = request.form()` in results *could be* giving the TypeError since `form` is a MultiDict as per [flask doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/?highlight=request%20form#flask.Request.form). Adding the `()` to the end looks like a callable function.

> **form**
>
> A MultiDict with the parsed form data from POST or PUT requests. Please keep in mind that file uploads will not end up here, but
>   instead in the files attribute.

---

The error message `TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable` should be giving a line number. Likely related to calling `login` with no `username` and `passsword` request form arguments.

Comment: Sorry about that. I had already fixed that. If you could help now, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Make sure current code is posted in question. And the TypeError should be giving exact line, add that to the question. Answer edited.

Comment: It is giving the line error on the line: result = request.form()

Comment: It is giving the line error on the line: result = request.form(). So my plan is as follows: after the login page, the user will get a search page where he can input the details of the book, then he will be redirected to page called books.html, where he can select which book he wants to use, and once clicked it can go to the book.html where he can submit reviews and read the description.